# Anchors for moving Game Objects in ARCore using Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

As per the documentation below:

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/developer-guides/anchors

Anchors can be created in the context of Trackable and ARCore Session. This works perfectly only if the object is not moving, as the object moves a few meters away from the anchor, anchors don't work. If I try to move the game objects in the real environment without creating anchors, as soon as, ARCore tracking adjusts with the environment, the position of the moving game object is also affected. Is there any way to even have anchors for moving game objects in the real environment or a way that game object doesn't drift when ARCore tracking updates?

Comment: Hi, are you saying you are attaching a gameobject to an anchor and the gameobject drifts?  The whole point of creating an anchor is to ensure the gameobject doesn't move.

Comment: The situation here is if the game object is not moving and we assign an anchor, the game object doesn't drift, but if the game object is moving and also away from the anchor, it deviates. As, anchors must be placed closely not farther than few meters away from the Game Object.

Comment: Why dont you change the position of the anchor for moving your object. Since your objects are childs of the anchor they will move with it.